# How can I hide button onclick of another button in scss?

Tags: html, angular, sass

I want to change the property of class when click on `Show` button. When `Show` button is clicked `data class` dropdown button should hide. For trial I tried to apply background color property on hover, that worked fine. But when onclick try to hide `data class dropdown` that did not worked.  How can I achieve such functionality using above approach o

Comment: Why do you want to achieve that in pure scss ? it can be done programmatically

Answer (score 0):

In your `component.ts` you can have a variable called `shouldHide`, like:

```js
  // component.ts
  shouldHide = false;
```

And you can toggle this on click, and hide the data class div based on that state:

```html
<!-- component.html -->
<ng-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="button" class="check" />
        <label class="filter-button" for="button" (click)="toggling()">Monday </label>
        <div class="filters">
          <div class="data" *ngIf="shouldHide">
            <overlay [dropdownLabel]="i18nLabelService.investment.translation">
            </overlay>
          </div>
          <div class="option-bar" *ngIf="showFilterOverlay">
            <button (click)="shouldHide = !shouldHide">Show {{Data?.length }}/{{ DataTable.length }}
              funds</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
```

To do it via CSS, you can add a conditional class, like:

```html
<!-- component.html -->
<ng-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="button" class="check" />
        <label class="filter-button" for="button" (click)="toggling()">Monday </label>
        <div class="filters">
          <div class="data" [class.hidden]="shouldHide">
            <overlay [dropdownLabel]="i18nLabelService.investment.translation">
            </overlay>
          </div>
          <div class="option-bar" *ngIf="showFilterOverlay">
            <button (click)="shouldHide = !shouldHide">Show {{Data?.length }}/{{ DataTable.length }}
              funds</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
```

And then in your scss:

```
div.data {
  &.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible using pseudo class selector or any other css properties?

Comment: Yeah definitely, I edited my post to include how to hide via scss.

Comment: You have been mistaken. On clicking option-bar class button div class dropdown should hide

Comment: Oh ok, yeah I misunderstood. I don't see the div class dropdown in the markup.

Where is that dropdown? Is it inside the `<overlay>` element?

Comment: Yes in overlay, wrapped in same div